# github commands

Tags: git, github

I want to create a new branch, get a repository, change a file and push it to the repository.

these commands are the right way?

```
git checkout -b marker_up_down          //create a branch and make it as a default
git clone git@github.com:user/mygit.git // get the repository of mygit
```

assuming I change a file is named: "main.html" and want to push it, so I do:

```
git add path/main.html
git commit                             // add a comment of this push
git push origin marker_up_down
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: No, they are not. You can't create a branch in repository you didn't clone yet.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - He wants to know if his commands in the first block are correct.

Comment: I am afraid to do something wrong with the github commands, so I want to make sure that I do it correctly..

Comment: You probably don't want to clone a repository into another one unless you're doing something with subrepos.

Comment: You are not doing any github commands at all. git commands, perhaps, but no github ones.

Comment: I want to know if all the commands are correct (not only in the first block). please tell me what the commands I should do are..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is to

1. Clone the remote repository
   `git clone git@github.com:user/mygit.git`
2. Create a branch
   `git checkout -b marker_up_down`
3. Change (edit) your file
4. Add and commit your file
   `git add path/main.html`
   `git commit`
5. Push the change to remote
   `git push origin marker_up_down`

Comment: thank you but if I clone the repository I will have to keep them in sync. there is a way that I won't have to keep them in sync?

Comment: @AlonShmiel: that doesn't make any sense. You can't sensibly push into a remote repository without first merging, since you have no idea what other people's pushes may have done it it. If no one else is changing it, then it's the pushes themselves that keep it in sync; that's the whole point of pushing.